# C# - How to hide window from “Applications” tab in task manager?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I Want To Make A Program By C#(Console Or Windows Application).
I Want Hide My App from “Applications” tab in task manager

I Dont Want Do This By:

```
Form1.Text="";
```

I want User Show Nothing in Applications Tab In Task Manager.
Any Body Know What I Do This?

Comment: Why would you EVER need this?

Comment: Simple, it isn't possible.

Comment: It's not possible in C# although some malware can cloak DLL's being loaded into another process. I can't think of any reasonable reason to wish to do this - perhaps explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around to hide it from the task manager, but you could just disguise it by making it show up as `"svchost.exe"`

The programs are available in `task manager` to examine the processes running on your computer by user.